# No route registered for '/docker/hook'

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-web-app-for-containers

I'm creating an Azure AppService based on a Docker image. The image is in Docker public registry, so I want the service to 'know' when there's a new version of the image (same tag).

I thought the WebHook under Continuous Deployment was to achieve that, but when I call it with curl I get the message from the subject.

I couldn't find the right doc... is that WebHook URL for what I think (hope) it is? is there a specific HTTP verb to use?

**EDIT**: I mean the WebHook URL found under Continuous Deployment in my Container Settings in Azure

[image]

Comment: Do you mean WebHook in Docker or WebHook in AzureDevops?

Comment: Yes, I'll add that to the question

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this?

Comment: No, I did not. I quit trying:(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was stuck on this one for some time as well, until I realized that it requires POST HTTP request on that URL.

Here is an example of the CURL request that I have in my gitlab CI script

```
curl -X POST "https://\$$AZURE_DEPLOY_USER:$AZURE_DEPLOY_PASSWORD@$AZURE_KUDU_URL/docker/hook" -d -H
```

It does require to have set the following variables in the environment or you can replace it directly with your URL

- `$AZURE_DEPLOY_USER`
- `$AZURE_DEPLOY_PASSWORD`
- `$AZURE_KUDU_URL`

Comment: Or you can just try to send a POST request on the URL in postman

Comment: Thanks, must have overlooked this in the documentation

Comment: @zdarsky.peter Thanks it helped me too. Already upvoted ;) Just wanted to ask if there is any way to change the docker image tag as well with the trigger? I am trying to setup a Gitlab CI/CD to deploy docker container to Azure web app.